# C# Eto.Forms - как сделать закруглённую форму

Tags: c#, gui, кроссплатформенность

Возникла необходимость создать небольшое кроссплатформенное приложение на C#. Выбрал за основе Eto.Forms, т.к. довольно простой как по мне фреймворк. Но возникла проблема: мне нужно сделать форму закруглённой, а не квадратной... Я пробовал ставить
`WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None` и `BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent`, но это приводит к "дорисовки" формы до прямоугольника белым / чёрным цветом (зависит от ОС)... Также, пробовал "нативные" костыли [Уж помолчу о линукс/макос], например `WpfHelpers.ToNative(this).AllowsTransparency = true` - это также НЕ работает. В WinForms есть Region параметр и ContentClip, но аналогов на Eto.Forms найти не удалось.
Можно ли как-то реализовать закруглённую форму на этом фреймворке? Сразу скажу, **сменить фреймворк нет возможности**.

Comment: В первый раз слышу про этот гуй. Попробуйте на англоязычном StackOverflow задать этот вопрос. Там шанс получить ответ на такую экзотику выше.

Comment: Если не изменяет память это кроссплатформенная обертка над разными либами(wpf. gtk и тд). И соотвествено окна они "рисуют" нативно. У них там есть так называемые [Custom Platform Controls](https://github.com/picoe/Eto/wiki/Custom-Platform-Controls). но скорее всего окошко в это не входит.

Comment: Как я уже и написал, я пробовал получать "нативную" версию (по крайней мере под винду) окна и в сырую редактировать параметры. Успехом не увенчалось, всё равно окно дорисовывается до прямоугольной формы :(